# Import JavaFX Packages To Run Through Command Line/CMD

Tags: java, javafx, cmd, visual-studio-code

So I am attempting to develop a JavaFX program using my favourite editor (Visual Studio Code) and then run that program through the windows 10 Command Prompt Command Line using

> javac program.java

then

> java program

I am currently running  jdk & jre 1.8.0_181 (which I have been told already includes the JavaFX packages) however I keep getting compilation errors saying that the packages dont exist

> Error: Package javafx.collections does not exist.
>
> ```
> import javafx.collections.*;
>
> ^
> ```

I am currently in my third year of an information technology degree at university and on my university computers, javafx programs run completely normally just using the commands mentioned above however when I attempt to recreate these on my personal laptop, I get those errors. I know my program has no coding errors because it worked on their version with no compilation/runtime errors. If anyone can suggest any reasons why this may be happening (i.e. there is something I need to do to setup my javafx properly or I need to use a specific command to run the program) it would really help. Thanks.

Comment: You're definitely using OracleJDK 8 and not OpenJDK 8, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I tried the 1.8.0_191 from Oracle and that didnt work @Slaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was the one to originally ask the question but I just found a solution that happens to work and for those in the future who have this issue, I uninstalled ALL versions of java that I had running on my computer completely through the "Add or Remove Programs" page. Once done I installed specifically this version of Java (none of the others worked properly for me but this may differ for you): Java SE Development Kit 8u192 (Found at https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). Once installed, find your Java directory in your Program Files directory "C:\Program Files", and open the jdk folder that you just installed. Get the path to this folder and copy it to the clipboard. Open your control panel, click on "System and Security" (if you cannot find this button, skip to the next step). Click on "System" > "Advanced System Settings" (on the left bar). Click the "Advanced" tab at the top, then "Environmental Variables..." at the bottom. Under "System Variables", look for a variable called JAVA_HOME. If you cannot find it, click "New", enter "JAVA_HOME" into the "Variable Name" field, and enter the path you copied to the clipboard earlier into the "Variable Value" field. Click "OK". Next find the "Path" variable and click edit. Look for a directory in the list similar to "C:\Program Files\Java{some jdk here}\bin". If you find one, click it, click delete on the right and then click new. Then in the created text field, enter "%JAVA_HOME%\bin". Click "OK" until all of the windows we opened are closed. The javac should now work with JavaFX.